# Border radius not applied if backface-visibility hidden on child element

Tags: css, css-transforms

I have a couple of divs, one inside the other, I'm using `border-radius` and `overflow: hidden` on the outer div which creates a circular mask over the inner div.

It works, however, when using `backface-visibility: hidden;` on the child div the `border-radius` is no longer applied.

[Here's an example of the issue](http://jsbin.com/iWOcOgiy/1/edit), can be seen in chrome and safari

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like this is a bug in webkit it's being tracked on the [chromium issue track](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=157218). Looks like no sign of a fix being merged any time soon.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, i've tried a few things with your example. The W3schools states that "backface-visibility:hidden;" is not yet well supported. This property has to do with 3d transformations, right? Specially rotation.


I found a workaround. Apply the "backface-visibility" on the mask div, not the inner one. If you do that, you'll see that it breaks the round as well. But if you apply a rotation transform on the mask div, the rounded border appears back to normal.


So, if you really want to hide the backface without losing the radius, apply this style only after you started rotating the element. Check this out:

```
<p>Backface hidden:</p>
<div class="ex">
  <div class="mask bfh">
    <div class="bg"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

And the css:

```
.bfh {
  -webkit-backface-visibility:hidden;
  -webkit-transform: rotateY(30deg);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this, just trying this with a full example.

Answer (score 1):

In @Rob linked track on chrome issue there is also a workaround that was added by [user **viktorli**](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=157218#c19).

Simply add a `transform` rule on the parent element of the rogue child not respecting the `overflow:hidden` rule and it will be fixed! something like:

`-webkit-transform: scale(1);`